Azure Blazor WASM Post Login Redirect
I have a Net6 Blazor WASM project where all pages / routes of the project require "Authorization" through the Azure Entra identity platform. I would like to share links to the pages that require authorization. However, upon authorization through the Azure Entra, the users is redirected to https://my-website.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback as part of the app registration.
EDIT:
User-case:
I would like to share a link to my webpage requiring authentication, i.e. https://my-website.azurewebsites.net/custom-link-A. The user signs into Entra and once signed-in is redirected to .../custom-link-A. If I send a different link, also requiring authentication i.e. .../custom-link-B I would like the user to be re-directed to this URL after authentication.
Requirement: I would like to have a dynamic re-direct dependent upon the URL link the user is trying to open. I also do not want to hard-code every redirect link possible into my app-registration.
Hopefully this is achievable as it must be a common user scenario.

We shall have codes below in blazor wsam app Program.cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
});

Put the mouse over Authentication in VS and press F12, we would see properties like screenshot below,

which defines the default redirect URL, so that we could modify it in appsettings.json, I have configurations like below，like you see I try to convert the redirect url to /counter.
"AzureAd": {
  "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id",
  "ClientId": "client_id",
  "ValidateAuthority": true,
  "RedirectUri": "/counter"
}

Then I also need to add it to Azure AD, then I put the @attribute [Authorize] in FetchData blade, so that I don't need to sign in when visiting the index page.

Have a test in my side, when I click to visit FetchData blade, it asked me to sign in, but with the default popup mode would cause this issue.

Therefore, I changed the mode to redirect
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
});

Then it worked in my side, when I visit FetchData, it redirects to sign-in page. After signing in successfully, it redirect to Counter blade.

Thanks for the suggestion. However I have updated my user-scenario to make it clear that I would like to share possible many different URL links with users, however all required authentication. Therefore a different redirect URL will be required... is there a way to have a dynamic redirect following login?

no, we can only try to have a workaround for dynamic redirect url. just like you see, we need to set the redirect url in advance in Azure AD. Normal workaround is that, we set a url distribution center as the redirect url, then try to figure out which url is required to redirect to, then do the redirection in that page.

Thanks - is there any way we can set the original requested URL can be re-sent as a query parameter in the static redirect URL? So the single distribution can read the query parameter and redirect from the distribution page?

I think the below could also be a relevant link... but am not sure how to implement.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#redirecttologin-component

is there any way we can set the original requested URL can be re-sent as a query parameter in the static redirect URL --> per my understanding, when we don't change anything in the code, for example, I just added [Authorize] attribute on FetchData.razor, then when I click to visit this blade, it would redirect to login site and after we sign in successfully, it would redirect back to FetchData.razor, the same for counter.razor.... The link you shared is based on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication package, which is different from the package I shared, what I used

is Microsoft.Identity.Web and Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI
